# Creepy video on Youtube, with secret cipher built in

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, number-sequence, language, letters

This showed up in r/deepintoyoutube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1ExfbH4Jew

I've posted it around, and no one has solved it. I believe it is a cipher for a couple of reasons, at the end 26 unique letters are listed (could be arranged as a key?), and the numbers listed throughout the video are numbered 1-26. I don't think it is standard Caesar cipher. Here is what I know:

The numbers listed in the video are:

1 18 10 10 2 20 9 10 10 17 24 5 15 10 6 17 26 16 22 5 25 17 6 12 23 23 2 10 14 22 14 10 6 11 12 5 10 17 10 12 26

followed by these letters at the end: tgnauhobvipcwjqdxkreylsfzm

I put the video on slow and did some research. The video is shot in Sydney, Nova Scotia, Canada. First I noticed a Canadian Diabetes donation center, and a flag. Then I saw the word Mayflower Mall at the fair grounds. Looked up mayflower flower mall, found that it was located in Sydney. Also I confirmed this by googling the Hampton in that shows up in very short clips in the film. Same hotel, you can also see the grounds of the hotel show up in several shots.

If you slow down the video you can see a scary clown twice. Once at the end, standing at the end of a dark hallway holding a knife, and another time you can briefly see the same gown the clown is wearing hanging up.

View this post for some ideas from other people:

https://www.reddit.com/r/codes/comments/6nq3df/creepy_video_found_on_a_usb_with_a_mysterious/

Comment: Arjjbtijjqxeojfqzpveyqflwwbjnvnjfklejqjlz And Tkiigeviixfuqinxmdluzxhcsshijljihpcixicm Are the messages I got from changing numbers to letters. I tried ceasear shifting them. Don't waste your time.

Comment: One of the reddit comments mentioned something: 

What you get when you take the numbers as indices of the string at the end: tkiigeviixfuqihxmdluzxhcssgijljihpcuixicm, when you reverse the string at the end (or take 26 - each number) and do the same you get: zbddfhxddvgypdevmiaytvejnnfdcacdeqjydvdjm, however if you run any of these, Including the straight a-z conversion through a substitution solver (guballa.de/substitution-solver) you get: bussingssacrystalformateddispopsthersasel.

Answer (score 3):

### Partial Answer

After scouring the internet for a bit, I saw that someone on Reddit had discovered the key to the letter string at the end of the video:

> tgnauhobvipcwjqdxkreylsfzm

is actually

> `t    u    v    w    x    y    z
>   g    h    i    j    k    l    m
>    n    o    p    q    r    s
>     a    b    c    d    e    f`

which is the alphabet backwards, un-flattened into diagonal lines and with two rows changed. (The Reddit post had the lines unchanged and quit there; the rest of this is my work.)

We can apply that to the text indicated by the numbers in the video (where A = 1, B = 2, etc.), so we get:

> ARJJBTIJJQXEOJFQZPVEYQFLWWBJNVNJFKLEJQJLZ

which translates to:

> `A   B   J   O   Z   Y   W   N   F   J   Z
>   J   I   X   F   V   F   B   N   L   J
>    R   T   Q   J   P   Q   W   V   K   Q
>     J   J   E   Q   E   L   J   J   E   L`

If we form that back into text like the original key was arranged, we get:

> JJEQELJJELRTQJPQWVKQJIXFVFBNLJABJOZYWNFJZ

Taking that a step further, if we reduce this in size to be only 26 letters in the same positions as the key, we get:

> `A   B   J   O   Z   Y   W 
>   J   I   X   F   V   F   B
>    R   T   Q   J   P   Q
>     J   J   E   Q   E   L`

Which flattens, similarly, to:

> JJEQELRTQJPQJIXFVFBABJOZYW

Unfortunately, I haven't gotten much further past this. I've mostly focused on substitution, and am getting a lot of nearly-not-nonsense, but nothing super promising yet. BUT I think this is all in the right direction, maybe someone else can take it from here.

Comment: Hmm maybe it's a keyboard substitution